# Python - Word Scramble Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

While this assignment is past due (I joined the class late unfortunately) I still need to figure it out. I have the following list of words:

abhor:hate
bigot:narrow-minded, prejudiced person
counterfeit:fake; false
enfranchise:give voting rights
hamper:hinder; obstruct
kindle:to start a fire
noxious:harmful; poisonous; lethal
placid:calm; peaceful
remuneration:payment for work done
talisman:lucky charm
abrasive:rough; coarse; harsh
bilk:cheat; defraud

I need to read this file into a dictionary, pick a random key, scramble it, then ask the user to solve it. Unlike other solutions on here, it does not iterate three times, but runs until the user enters 'n'. The code will ask the user after each round if the user wants to continue the game. The user can also type 'hint' to get the definition of the word.
There is a similar question here: (http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/302146-python-school-project-write-a-word-scramble-game-status-complete/) or rather the result of a question, but I am not knowledgeable enough to bridge the gaps and make it work for my purposes. None of the variation on this that I have seen on stack overflow come close enough for me to bridge the gap either, likely because I just don't know enough yet. Before we even start, this code does not yet work at all really, I am pretty lost at this point, so please be gentle. My code so far is below:

```
import random
from random import shuffle

#Reads the words.txt file into a dictionary with keys and definitions
myfile = open("words.txt", "r")
wordDict = dict([(line[:line.index(":")], line[line.index(":") +1 : -1]) 
    for line in myfile.readlines()])

#print (b)

def intro():
    print('Welcome to the scramble game\n')
    print('I will show you a scrambled word, and you will have to guess the word\n')
    print('If you need a hint, type "Hint"\n')

#Picks a random key from the dictionary b
def shuffle_word():
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    return wordKey

#Gives a hint to the user    
def giveHint(wordKey):
    hint = wordDict[wordKey]
    return hint

#Below - Retrieves answer from user, rejects it if the answer is not alpha    
def getAnswer():
    answer = input('\nEnter your first guess: ')
    while True:
            if answer.isalpha():
                return answer
            else:
                answer = input('\nPlease enter a letter: ')

def keepPlaying():
    iContinue = input("\nWould you like to continue? ")
    return iContinue    

def scramble():
    theList = list(shuffle_word())
    random.shuffle(theList)
    return(''.join(theList))


#Main Program

if keepPlaying() == 'y':
    intro()
    shuffle_word()
    randomW = shuffle_word()
    #scramKey = list(randomW)
    thisWord = scramble()
    print ("\nThe scrambled word is " +thisWord)
    solution = getAnswer()
    if solution == thisWord:
        print("\nCongratulations")
    if solution == 'Hint' or solution == 'hint':
        myHint = giveHint(wordKey)
        print(myHint)

else: 
    print("\nThanks for playing")
```

I have edited this post to ask for new information, though I am not sure if that ishow its properly done. Thanks to the help of those below, I have made progress, but am stuck not on a specific piece.
I have two questions. 1: How can I get the giveHint() function to return the definition of the random key selected by the shuffle_wprd() function. I know what I have above will not work because it is simply returning a string, but it seems like just using a dict.get() function would not get the correct definition for the random word chosen.
2: How can I get the program not to ask the user to continue on the first pass, but to then ask from then on. I thought about using a while loop and redefining the variable during the iteration, but I don't know enough to get it to work properly.
regardless, thank you to those people who have already helped me.

Comment: Please make your question more specific we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: My apologies, I was not asking for someone to send the assignment completed, I simply don't know enough to know what specific questions to ask. I was more looking to see if anyone could spot any obvious deficiencies in what I have already, or provide me with a resource on how to build a loop that iterates based on certain responses. How about this question: Why do I get an "undefined name 'wordKey'" error in the code above? It seems like I am defining it as a random key from the dictionary, but when I try to call it and use it, I get the above error.

Comment: Well undefined name wordKey basically means that no memory has been allocated for it. So, in other words, it doesn't exists. Which line is the error from?

Comment: I know roughly how to create a for loop. I'm more familiar with it in other languages. As far as linking to outside resources, that seems fairly ridiculous. Knowledge is knowledge, if knowledge as closely relevant as that exists on this site, I cannot find it, and providing that resource could help to answer my question or understand my reasoning. I will not hobble myself or anyone else who reads this topic to get help because of inter-website politics. If that doesn't sit well with you, then I respectfully thank you for your help, and will simply have to hope someone else is willing.

Comment: for loop in python is `for any_var in range(start, end, step):` https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop.

Comment: Thank you, I am working on the for loop now. Anything on the wordKey variable not working properly? I feel like I am missing something extremely simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out a bit, the length seems to be of no benefit as a hint as you can see the length of the scrambled word so I used the definition as the hint,I think you also want to ask the user to guess the word not individual letters:

```
from random import shuffle, choice

#Reads the words.txt file into a dictionary with keys and definitions
with open("words.txt") as f:
    word_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        # split into two parts, word and description
        word, hint = line.split(":")
        word_dict[word] = hint


def intro():
    print('Welcome to the scramble game\n')
    print('I will show you a scrambled word, and you will have to guess the word\n')


#Picks a random key from the dictionary b
def pick_word():
    word = choice(list(word_dict.keys()))
    return word


#Gives a hint to the user
def give_hint(word):
    # return the definition of the word
    descrip = word_dict[word]
    return descrip


#Below - Retrieves answer from user, rejects it if the answer is not alpha
def get_answer():
    while True:
        answer = input('Please enter a guess: ')
        if answer.isalpha():
            return answer
        else:
            print("Only letters in the word")


def main():
    intro()
    word = pick_word()
    # give user lives/tries
    tries = 3
    shffled_word = list(word)
    # shuffle the word 
    shuffle(shffled_word)
    # rejoin shuffled word
    shffled_word = "".join(shffled_word)
    # keep going for three tries as most
    while tries > 0:
        inp = input("Your scrambled word is {}\nEnter h if you want to see your hint or any key to continue".format(shffled_word))
        if inp == "h":
            print("The word definition is {}".format(give_hint(word)))
        ans = get_answer()
        if ans == word:
            print("Congratulations you win!")
            break
        tries -= 1
    # ask user if they want to play again, restarting main if they do
    play_again = input("Press 'y'  to play again or any key to exit")
    if play_again == "y":
        main()
    # else the user did not press y so say goodbye
    print("Goodbye")
main()
```

There are a few more bits to be added but I will leave that up to you.

Comment: dear lord, thank you. Using this as a reference when I get stuck will be invaluable.

Comment: No worries. It is a rough draught but the main logic is there.

Comment: So I need more information, but I am unsure how to post code snippets on this post again. Comment doesn't seem the place. I have figured a lot of it out, but I am having trouble getting the hint function to return the definition using the function above. It does not let me call to the variable 'word' in the above. It will only let me call the function that variable is defined in. I cannot seem to get the syntax to make that call to that function then return the definition.

Comment: give_hint(word) returns the definition

Comment: def shuffle_word():  
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))  
    return wordKey  

#Gives a hint to the user      
def giveHint(wordKey):  
    hint = wordDict[wordKey]  
    return hint     
This does not seem to work. Says its not defined

Comment: You are not using my function. If you look at my spelling and yours you will see the difference

Comment: Yea, It had to do with not using your dictionary method above. I was using index because its what the teacher taught, but I don't know enough about it to make it work for your code, so I changed it to your method and it seems to work. Now to figure out how to not make it ask the user to continue on the first pass (I cant use the three guess counter method). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all those who helped. For any who come along later, the final product is here. Similar to what Padraic Cunningham put, but without the three answer limit, and without his more elegant solution of wrapping the main program into a called function.

```
import random
from random import shuffle, choice

#Reads the words.txt file into a dictionary with keys and definitions
with open("words.txt") as f:
    wordDict = {}
    for line in f:
        # split into two parts, word and description
        word, hint = line.split(":")
        wordDict[word] = hint


#print (b)

def intro():
    print('Welcome to the scramble game\n')
    print('I will show you a scrambled word, and you will have to guess the word\n')
    print('If you need a hint, type "Hint"\n')

#Picks a random key from the dictionary b
def shuffle_word():
    wordKey = choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    return wordKey

#Gives a hint to the user    
def giveHint(wordKey):
    descrip = wordDict[word]
    return descrip

#Below - Retrieves answer from user, rejects it if the answer is not alpha    
def getAnswer():
    answer = input('\nEnter a guess: ')
    while True:
            if answer.isalpha():
                return answer
            else:
                answer = input('\nPlease enter a letter: ')

def getAnswer2():
    answer2 = input('\nEnter another guess: ')
    while True:
            if answer2.isalpha():
                return answer2
            else:
                answer2 = input('\nPlease enter a letter: ')

def keepPlaying():
    iContinue = input("\nWould you like to continue? ")
    return iContinue    

#def scramble():
#    theList = list(shuffle_word())
#    random.shuffle(theList)
#    return(''.join(theList))


#Main Program

while keepPlaying() == 'y':
    intro()
    #shuffle_word()
    randomW = shuffle_word()
    cheatCode = giveHint(randomW)
    #scramKey = list(randomW)
    thisWord = list(randomW)
    print(thisWord)
    random.shuffle(thisWord)
    print(thisWord)
    thisRWord = ''.join(thisWord)
    print ("\nThe scrambled word is " +thisRWord)
    solution = getAnswer()
    loopMe = False
    while loopMe == False:
        if solution == randomW:
            print("\nCongratulations")
            loopMe = True
        if solution == 'Hint' or solution == 'hint':
            print(cheatCode)
        if solution != randomW:
            loopMe = False
            solution = getAnswer2()
```